# How use URL ZF2 in my Entity Class

Tags: url, hyperlink, frameworks, zend-framework2

I must insert a link in an email that send to my user. So I have an Entity class that send this mail. But I don't know how i can create this link with "url" method of the view/controller system of ZF2.

My class is:

```
class UserEntity
{
  public function sendMail($user)
  {
      $link = $unknow->url("route",array("param" => "param")); //how can create this ? 
      $text = "click here $link";
      $this->sendMail($to,$text);
  }
}
```

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: This is a very very wrong place to do such a thing. Entities are Data-Objects and (almost) no more than that. Better outsource this into a Service and inject the URL ViewHelper via the ViewHelperManager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of design, it would be [considered bad practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) to have your domain model responsible for the creation of the URL (or anything else that that does not describe the entity in its simplest terms).

I would create a `UserService` that would encapsulate the a `SendMail` function where a `UserEntity` could be passed as an argument and it's `email` property used to send the email.

```
class UserService {

   protected $mailService;

   public function __construct(MailService $mailService) {
      $this->mailService = $mailService;
   }

   public function sendUserEmail(UserEntity $user, $message) {

      $this->mailService->send($user->getEmail(), $message);
   }  
}
```

The mail service could be another service encapsulating the `Zend\Mail\Transport` instances.

Your controller would use the `UserService` to send the mail to the correct user.

The `$message` which needs to include a URL that is generated using [the `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Url` controller plugin](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-url)

```
class UserController extends AbstractActionController {
   protected $userService;

   public function __construct(UserService $userService) {
     $this->userService = $userService;
   }  

   public function sendEmailAction() {
     // load $user from route params or form post data
     $user = $this->userService->findUserByTheirId($this->params('id'));         

     // Generate the url
     $url = $this->url()->fromRoute('user/foo', array('bar' => 'param1'));
     $message = sprintf('This is the email text <a href="%s">link</a>!', $url); 

     $this->userService->sendUserEmail($user, $message);
   }
}
```

These are contrived examples but my point is that you should only store information in your entity allowing you to "do stuff" *with* it, not *within* it.

Comment: Thanks for yout answare. So if I want, for example, send mail to verify user's mail address, i should write this in my controller:

public function registrationAction() 
{
  if ($this->userService->addUser($data)){
    $this->sendMail($data->user_email);  
  }
}

public function sendMail($email)
{
  $url = $this->url()->fromRoute("verifyLink");
  $text = "For verify your address click here $url";
  $this->userService->sendMail($email,$text);
}

Comment: Looks good; Remember my examples don't include the normal validation, so when you take an email address from the user you should be using correctly validated form data `$form->isValid() == true` and then create the user entity and send the email or whatever your needs are.